# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) angular 4 Post

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, angular4-httpclient

I am trying to access a wep api with angular 4 post method.

In my service, I've added content-type of application/json. And I'm converting the object into json while sending data to api. I am using HttpClientModule

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()

export class NewServiceService {

  baseUrl = "http://localhost:33969/api/";
  headers = { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) 
      };
  obj= {
    name:"A",
    cgpa: 3
  };

_http:any;
constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this._http = http;
}

SaveStudents(){

    this._http
    .post(
        this.baseUrl + 'home/Save', 
        JSON.stringify(this.obj),
        this.headers
     )
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      alert("Student Saved!");
    },
    err => {
      alert("Error!");
    }
  );
}}
```

In the API,

```
using Entity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Repo;

namespace API_Core.Controllers
{
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IStudent _student;
    public HomeController(IStudent student)
    {
        _student = student;
    }

    [HttpPost]   
    public Student Save([FromBody]Student s)
    {
        return _student.Save(s);
    }
}
}
```

here, I  want to catch the objtect as Student model and do something with the data. Here is the Student Model

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Cgpa { get; set; }
}
```

But when using prostman, I could succesfully receive the object.[image]

**UPDATE**
using HttpHeaders instead of Headers and CORS solved the issue

Enabling CORS for ASP.NET Core 2 =>

In ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors", builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
```

In Configure(Above usemvc()):

```
app.UseCors("Cors");
```

Comment: Saved my life with this edited answer! THX

Comment: Where do we find ConfigureServices and Configure in startup class ?
Can you show how to add those

Comment: @SujayUN those are methods that are created when the project is created go ahead a search inside the Startup.cs file and you will find them

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change the below line

```
  headers = { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) 
      };
```

to

```
headers={
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
}
```

Comment: after changing that line. It throws a new error 

"OPTIONS http://localhost:33969/api/home/Save net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Comment: Is your Angular app and the API hosted on different port? if yes, may be you need to enable CORS.

Comment: Yes. I've enabled Cors. I could successfully send a get request to the api and received proper data. But when i'm trying to do post, I'm facing problem

Comment: Can you post the request payload that is going out from the angular client? with Dev tools, or fiddler.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the 415 error was caused because I was calling `JSON.stringify(obj)` when there was no need for it. I read somewhere that post method will stringify the body parameter as needed

So instead of this:

```cs
this._http
.post(
    this.baseUrl + 'home/Save', 
    JSON.stringify(this.obj),
    this.headers
 )
```

I changed it to this:

```cs
this._http
.post(
    this.baseUrl + 'home/Save', 
    this.obj, // << no need to stringify 
    this.headers
)
```

Here is my actual working code

```cs
@Injectable()
export class ParkingService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(parking: Parking) {
    const requestUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'parking' ;
    const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();

    headerOptions.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(requestUrl, parking, {headers: headerOptions}) ;
  }
}
```

This happened to me even after enabling and configuring CORS on the .NET core web api

Comment: thanks buddy.. this one really helped me

Comment: unbelievable! this works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using angular 6 with .netcore 2. My code was this:

Angular:

```
  getCustomers(pageSize: number, pageNumber: number) {

    let fromObject = {
      name: this.searchName,
      pageNumber: pageNumber.toString(),
      pageSize: pageSize.toString()
    }

    const params = new HttpParams({
      fromObject: fromObject
    });

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, { params: params });

  }
```

.Net Core

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCustomers(PageSelection page)
```

The problem was solved with two different ways.

First one:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCustomers(string Name, int PageSize, int PageNumber)
```

Second one, although I had added [ApiController]

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCustomers([FromQuery]PageSelection page)
```

Hope it helps.